# acf/validate_save_post vs acf/save_post

Tags: wordpress, validation, advanced-custom-fields

I want to validate a post before to submit.
Is there any differences?

```
add_action('acf/validate_save_post', 'my_acf_validate_save_post');
function my_acf_validate_save_post() {
  // Do validate.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both actions are ajaxed before submit.

#### acf/validate_save_post

- No args.
- Cannot retrieve old post data.
- Get new post data from `$_POST`.
- You can set errors by using `acf_add_validation_error`. You must know html input name of ACF field. eg) `acf_add_validation_error( 'acf[field_628ca71315e3d]', 'Please check this input to proceed' );`

#### acf/save_post

- 1 arg: $post_id
- Get old ACF field values from `get_fields( $post_id )`. eg) `[ 'price' => 1000 ]`
- Get new ACF field values from `$_POST` with a part of html input names. eg) `[ 'field_628ca71315e3d' => 2000 ]`
- Cannot set errors.